# node.js res.download() using case-insensitive filename

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I am using this code for downloading a file from a server folder in node.js.

```
  res.set("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileNameOnly);
  res.set("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
  res.download(filePath + fileNameOnly, fileNameOnly, (err) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log('Impex Ctlr: There was an error in downloading document: ' + err);
      res.status(500).send({message: 'Download Error' + err})
    }
  });
```

**Required:** To be able to fetch the file using case-insensitive fileName (the var fileNameOnly in above code)

This code works if the file name provided is exactly matching(case-sensitive).

Any idea how to get it working with case-insensitive file name?

Comment: Convert everything to lowercase, the files on the fs & the "fileNameOnly" variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your filesystem that holds these files is a unix variant of some sort.  This means the file system is case-sensitive.  There are several ways to solve this problem, but most of them involve changing the server-side, and depending on your situation, this may or may not be possible.  Here's a link to get thoughts started on how to do this:
https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+filename+case+insensitive&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS859US859&oq=linux+filename+case+insensitive&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l2.8591j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

On the node side, I'm not aware of a way to do this, except for permutations, which I'm sure you'd want to avoid.

Comment: Thats terrible. Instead he should improve his code and not mess with the whole OS/filesystem...

Comment: i offered both as options, and I'm not sure what you're saying is terrible.  Perhaps a suggestion to solve his problem?

Comment: I gave him a possible solution. Convert everything to lowercase. Another possible solution is to use uuid's instead of the "real" filename. To mess with the filesystem should be the least obvious solution. Especially this is not a fs problem, more a poor application design, which can be more easier solved than to switch to a whole new fs/enable case-insensitiv flag. Too times you just pasted your google search request and not even a "real" solution... Thats why i said its a terrible solution...

Comment: i offered the same solution, deal with case sensitivity...in this case you're doing the same thing...changing the FS, by changing the files.  What if he gets new files?  he has to run everything this way, and keep sweeping